# Code Blocks(New project/Rename main file)

Tags: codeblocks

When I create a new project in code blocks `File->New->project->console application->Go->C++-><project title>->GNU compiler->finish` (both debug and release box are checked), Then a project is created having `.cpp` file with name of `main`.

My question is how to rename this main file.

Before asking this question I have tried to solve it, but it includes many steps.

I have tried two ways (one way gives me a solution, and the other way indicates that file has been corrupted).

Actually I want to find a quick way to rename this main file?
If there is any method please tell me.

Two methods which I used(mentioning below)

1. `File->New->project->console application->Go->C++-><project title>->GNU compiler->finish`
   then go to local disc (where project is saved) rename `main` file. Open project again in code blocks. Open main file it says file does not exist.
   This method was quick but failed to rename main.
2. `File->New->project->console application->Go->C++-><project title>->GNU compiler->finish.
   then in code blocks at left side bar Sources/main/right click on main/remove file from project (then code blocks indicate you have deleted this main file but actually its not when I checked in local disk, main file was there). Then I create a new`.cpp` file as File/New/File and next simple steps.

So finally I got what I want. A new project with `.cpp` file (name of `.cpp` file that I want). But I'm not satisfied, I want a quick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture your code in a text file.
Close code::blocks
In the folder containing the files, rename all *.cpp and *.h or whatever your using including the cbp file. Don't need to change the depend or layout. Delete the bin and debug folders.
Double click the cbp (project file).
Remove the old files (right mouse click remove).
Then right mouse click on the project and select "add files".
Choose your newly named files, build and run.

Answer (score 5):

As of Code::Blocks 13.12 you can rename a file within a project
like this: Say the file to be renamed is `main.cpp` in project
`MyApp`.

- In the C::B **Management** pane navigate in the **Projects** tree-view to
  **Projects** -> **MyApp** -> **Sources** -> **main.cpp**.
- Right-click on the file-icon of **main.cpp**. A pop-up menu appears.
  The third item on the menu is **Rename file**. You can take it from there

Comment: In order for the **Rename file...** option to appear, the file cannot be open in the editor.

Comment: How can we rename the project itself?

Comment: @H.R. <workspace> -> *MyProject* -> **Properties** -> **Project Settings** -> **Title**. Edit.

Answer (score 0):

In **Code::Blocks 16.01**, assuming your project and files are open:

- If you want to rename `main.cpp` then, in the **Management** window, **Projects** tab, navigate to the **Sources** folder of your project and right-click on `main.cpp`. In the context menu that appears, if you find `Close main.cpp` menu item — click it! otherwise click `Rename file...`
- If you want to rename the title of your project, in the **Management** window, **Projects** tab, right-click on the title of your project. In the context menu that appears click `Properties...` to open the **Project/targets options** window, and type the new title of your project in the `Title` field. NOTE that this will **not** change the name of the project folder or the name of your project's `.cbp` file, because the title of your project is stored inside the `.cbp` file.
- If you want to rename **any** file or folder in your project, first close the project using the **File** menu, then, in the **Management** window,  **Files** tab, navigate to the desired file or folder, right-click on it and choose `Rename...`. Proceed with care. You might want to delete old `.depend`and `.layout` files that are no longer associated with your project.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of CodeBlocks, simply **close the file editor** and right click on the file (at left tree) -> **Rename File**.

[image]